# SharePoint List Name is not updated for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I have recently renamed SharePoint List Name by going to **List Settings** and from there **Name and Description** and renamed the list. However, some users see the old SharePoint List Name. This also happened with the Top menu bar which I solved the problem after deleting and creating the same menu bar item again. The list has plenty of items recorded so I can not just delete and create the same list again. Does anyone know what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the list or site experience setting to **classic experience**, then go to the list setting page and change the list name again.

If still does not work, **clear browser cache** history from the other user machine who is facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Rahaman, unfortunately clearing the cache and switching between old and modern experiences while renaming the list name did not solve the problem. I have never faced a problem such as this before.

Comment: Ohh... by the way where user seeing the old list name? Are they also going to list setting page? Or in the URL?

Comment: They see updated URL however the list name remains old. They can't go to list setting page because of privacy settings.

Comment: Seems like I solved the issue. The default language for SharePoint admin was different than the default language of some users. By using the same default language for all users, the page automatically updated the changes.